# Aggregating quarterly data sets for dynamic averages in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have quarterly expenditure data that look like this:

Q1:

```
ID  TRANS
1   454
2   370
3   40
4   0
```

Q2:

```
ID  TRANS
1   100
2   400
3   303
4   43
5   0
6   100
```

Q3:

```
ID  TRANS
3   20
6   300
7   400
8   300
9   100
```

Q4:

```
ID  TRANS
3   231
7   100
8   240
9   100
10  102
```

Ultimately, I'd like to end up with a dataset that has columns for TRANS in each quarter, and then averages them based on the number of non-zero inputs in the code.

So, for example, the final dataset would look something like this:

```
ID  T1  T2  T3  T4  TOT AVG
1   454 100 0   0   554 554/2
2   370 400 0   0   770 770/2
3   40  303 20  231 594 594/4
4   0   43  0   0   43  43/1
5   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   100 300 0   400 400/2
7   0   0   400 100 500 500/2
8   0   0   300 240 540 540/2
9   0   0   100 100 200 200/2
10  0   0   0   102 102 102/1
```

With T1 - T4 being the quarterly values (0 if 0 is written, or if no value is recorded), and AVG being the average of these values, dependent on the number of entries in T1 - T4.

Thus, if there were 2 values for ID #7, then the total would be divided by 2.  (I left the AVG category in dividend/divisor format so you could see the logic there).

This seems a little complicated for a basic merge() function, in particular the tallying and dynamic averaging at the end.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This frame work should get you started, depending on how many rows/columns you have, parts of it could be automated.  It starts with a merge and then uses rowMeans to et your average. It is only a framework, and could definitely be optimized.

```
#dummy data frames

ID <- c(1,2,3,4)
TRANS <- c(0,370,0,0)

T1 <-data.frame(ID,TRANS)

ID <- c(1,9,5,6,7)
TRANS <- c(123,456,40,789,987)

T2 <-data.frame(ID,TRANS)


#renaming "TRANS" to a "T*"
colnames(T1)<-c("ID","T1")
colnames(T2)<-c("ID","T2")


#Merging the frames, setting the row name to the ID make it easier to average rows.
Merged_fr <- transform(merge(x =T1, y =T2,all = TRUE, by = "ID"),row.names= ID, ID = NULL)

# set 0's to NA
Merged_fr[Merged_fr == 0] <- NA

#average rows

Merged_fr$AVG = rowMeans(Merged_fr, na.rm = TRUE)

#Set NA's to 0

Merged_fr[is.na(Merged_fr)] <- 0
```

Comment: Just ran this -- will definitely get me started!  I'll check back in and mark your answer when I've adopted it to my exact data!

Comment: Ultimately you need a couple more steps, in particular your merged_fr is only going to merge two dataframes, so you have to keep merging your merges, which is kinda what I wanted to avoid, but I'm going to go ahead and mark this correct anyway :)

Comment: I was thinking, depending on how you are loading you data in, you could create a vector containing all of you tables, and use one for loop to rename the columns, and the other to merge the whole list.